# awk/sed/grep to search for substring within string of second semicolon separated part/column and return only first part/column plus the substring

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a Unix file containing semicolon separated records like below, having 2nd part/column a string with comma separated values, like below:

```
789651234512;TEST-10=5,TEST-136=6,TEST-3=1,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-9=4,TEST-9013=100
132567123784;TEST-3=1,TEST-136=5,TEST-15=4,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=3
132564013784;TEST-3=1,TEST-15=4,TEST-4=2,TEST-5=8
132496583212;TEST-13=4,TEST-136=7,TEST-23=1,TEST-6=2,TEST-5=3,TEST-4=5,TEST-6=11
```

I want to find all TEST-136=X, when exists, where X can be any interger number from 1 and up to 3 digits and return them like, for above example:

```
789651234512;TEST-136=6
132567123784;TEST-136=5
132496583212;TEST-136=7
```

I am using the below awk, but that returns whole string of 2nd part/column:

```
awk -F'[;]' '/TEST-136/{ print $1";"$2 }' file.txt
```

However, I need to get only the 1st part/column and also the TEST-136=X part of the 2nd part/column, as said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assumes ONE match per line/record.

```sh
$ awk -F';' 'match($0, /TEST-136=[[:digit:]]+/) {print $1, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' OFS=';' kostas.txt
789651234512;TEST-136=6
132567123784;TEST-136=5
132496583212;TEST-136=7
```

Comment: That would match and print part of `CONTEST-136=123456789` which may not be desirable. There's no need to put `-` in a bracket expression btw, it's already literal in a regexp as long as it's NOT inside a bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/^([^;]*;).*(TEST-136=[^,]*).*/\1\2/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Perl,

```
$ perl -F";" -lane ' /(TEST-136=\w+)/ and print "$F[0];$1" ' kostas.txt
789651234512;TEST-136=6
132567123784;TEST-136=5
132496583212;TEST-136=7
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
$ awk -F"[;,]" ' { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/TEST-136/) print $1 ";" $i } ' kostas.txt
789651234512;TEST-136=6
132567123784;TEST-136=5
132496583212;TEST-136=7
$
```